# postgresql connection and setting autocommit off

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi, autocommit

I am programming in perl and have an existing connection (progammatically) with my postgres database. After the connection is established, I do not control the connection code, I want to set autocommit to off.

How does one do that? When I do it interactively, I do not see any changes. I \set autocommit off and then do an insert and I see the change. I do a rollback, I get there is no transaction exists.

I want to set autocommit off, do my work and then commit. How does one accomplish that with an existing connection?

Thanks
Reza

Comment: Any reason you can't use a regular transaction?

Answer (score 5):

You should not disable *autocommit* in a middle of connection, as it is unexpected and error prone.

The best is to explicitly start and end transactions using something like this:

```
$dbh->begin_work();
foreach($statement1, $statement2, $statement3) {
  $dbh->execute($_)
    or do { $dbh.rollback(); return -1 }
}
$dbh->commit();
```

`begin_work()` will temporarily turn autocommit off, until next commit or rollback.

But if you think you really need to hurt yourself, then perl won't stop you:

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
```